# Vala regex using groups with subgroups keeps ending in a segmentationfault

Tags: regex, vala

It is really simple. I am trying to use regex to indentify certain property values in a line of a vcard string.

So, here's the code:

```
int main(string[] args){

string input = "TEL;VALUE=uri;PREF=1;TYPE=\"voice,home\":tel:+1-555-555-5555;ext=5555";



string regString = "(tel:(?<phnum>.*);)*(?<pref>PREF=1;)*";

Regex regex = new Regex(regString);
MatchInfo match;

regex.match(input_end, 0, out match);

stdout.printf(match.fetch_named("phnum"));

stdout.printf(match.fetch_named(pref));

return 0;
```

}

What i want to do, really, is to say that the tag phnum applies to a subgroup of characters, when it appears in the input (hence the *, at the outside of the group). so when i do: `match.fetch_named("phnum")` the returned value would be: "+1-555-555-5555".

I am just getting segmentation faults, even though regex tester apps seem to accept the pattern well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things that can be done to improve the Vala code:

- GLib's `Regex` binding to PCRE will return an error message giving some details about an invalid regular expression. In Vala this message can be read by putting `new Regex ()` in a `try...catch` block.
- `regex.match()` returns `true` when a match is found, so wrapping `regex.match()` in an `if` statement makes the program more robust
- Vala has the null coalescing operator, `??`, which is a convenient way of providing an alternative value when there is a null value
- `MatchInfo` has the `next()` method and when combined with Vala's `do {} when ()` loop gives a good way of retrieving multiple matches safely

The regex you are using needs to exclude the terminating character, `;`. So `tel:(?<phnum>[^;|.]*);` would match all characters excluding `;` after `tel:` until `;` is reached.

Here is a working example putting all that together:

```
int main () {

  string input = "TEL;VALUE=uri;PREF=1;TYPE=\"voice,home\":tel:+1-555-555-5555;ext=5555";

  string regString = "tel:(?<phnum>[^;|.]*);|PREF=(?<pref>[0-9]*);";
  Regex regex;
  MatchInfo match;
  try {
    regex = new Regex(regString);
    if (regex.match(input, 0, out match)) {
      do {
        stdout.printf("Phone number: %s\n", match.fetch_named("phnum") ?? "None");
        stdout.printf("Preference: %s\n", match.fetch_named("pref") ?? "None");
      }
      while (match.next());
    }
  }
  catch (Error error) {
    print (@"$(error.message)\n");
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Phone number: 
Preference: 1
Phone number: +1-555-555-5555
Preference: None
```

There are two matches. What is interesting is the first match returns empty string for the phone number. This is because it is a valid sub-pattern, but didn't match anything. Why `pref` is null for the second match is unclear to me. That needs some more investigation as to what is going on in the regex engine, but this hopefully gives you enough to get on with.

Comment: Excellent!

Though, will this also work if PREF=1; is not in the input string at all?

Answer (score 1):

`printf` takes a format string first. You need to change those to:

```
stdout.printf("%s\n", match.fetch_named("phnum"));

stdout.printf("%s\n", match.fetch_named("pref"));
```

If the format string is null, `printf` will segfault.

If you don't want to bother with a format string, you can use [`FileStream.puts`](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.FileStream.puts.html), but you still need a null check:

```
if (match.fetch_named("phnum")!=null)
  stdout.puts(match.fetch_named("phnum"));
```

Comment: This solves the Segmentationfault, thanks.

But I still can not seem to form a regex where i could do the above and then do:

´match.fetch_named("phnum")´ and ´match.fetch_named("pref")´

Answer (score 1):

In think `regex.match(input_end` should also be `regex.match(input`

Without taking the exact format of the phone number into account, one possible solution  could be to match the allowed characters in a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and get the value from the group named `phnum`

`tel:(?<phnum>[0-9+-]+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pj8syH/1) | [Test it online](https://tio.run/##PU/LasMwELzrKxadZPzAOfjQqErowYVCCiFNCyUJRSRrWxDLRpHSQOm3u7JMethldpgZZq/yLIdBaQutVJpdrFG63h1AmvoS/RAyEaB07ywIoNtyxT@eVu@lcEbx9aZ8FjO@/VyXYk@vnTpi0nQt7unc4nkez9KiKO5TcLxZMQLK77kG67cJ@ezRwpaPfaNdu9jl6UOcHuLIi8kGa7yNYr8FaPyGwLB/e8TJq7TH5kVXnf/EI@8K@ixcLDyQQJ5A5@ykiMYWJ39mvY@wFQtsVqHfX1q2eGI0dKGRlxq0zmjIOfkdhj8)

Or a bit more broader match could be to use a negated character class `[^` to match what you don't want and get the value from group named `phnum`

`tel:(?<phnum>[^\r\n;]+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pj8syH/2)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be shortened to:

```
tel:(?<phnum>.*);$
```

Now `'phnum'` Group will contain the phone number.